# Troubleshooting DHCP relay

Tags: wireless-networking, dhcp

I have a home network with two routers connected through LAN. The main router is connected to the Internet.

I've had connection issues with WIFI clients walking through the house as the client doesn't get a new IP as needed. This was solved disabling the DHCP server on the secondary router.

Now, I've changed ISP and I've run into problems. Disabling DHCP results in the client not obtaining an IP.

I think the problem is with the main router (the new one) not serving DHCP through LAN. The DHCP relay seems to be disabled. Is there a workaround?

Main router: 192.168.1.1
Secondary: 192.168.0.1 (WAN IP 192.168.1.35)

The wired connection works fine (this computer is wired to the secondary router) and with DHCP Server enabled, the client navigates without problem.

**Update:** This also affects my home network, as the computers can't see each other.

Comment: My ISP told me to put their machine on 192.168.0.1 as well. Now, I can't see the other router (or hub, whatever)... sigh (I can always reset the boxes, no problem there).